# Does this edit not make the post easier to read?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I am just asking this question for information.

My [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16324576) was rejected due to:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
> easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
> completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Is this really not easier to read?

Comment: assuming that's all the edit is i would say it was an incorrect rejection. sure it doesn't really make it easier to read but it does correct that the quoted text isn't actually quotes

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The edit was rejected by the author of the post, rather than random reviewers. We can only guess why the author did that, but I suspect it *probably* would have been approved if it was reviewed by random reviewers.

That being said, you could have done better by:

- not making the first sentence bold;
- adding the missing `}` to make the `foreach` loop valid;
- fixing the grammar mistakes (such as "in cart but it return blank page") as well as "flow" of the post, in general, I find that questions are substantially clearer if they describe the problem first and then post the code;
- adding the missing [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag.

I [edited the post now](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44359678/revisions).

All of that being said, this question is rather vague as it doesn't include an actual error, and should probably be closed because of that.

Comment: Maybe it gives a blank page because of the syntax error caused by the missing `}` at the end?

Comment: This answer have batter explanation as above I accepted. Is question have multiple accepted answer (Any Issue)? or I un-accept the above and marked this is accepted answer?

Comment: Yeah, that's possible @Pang, although I would consider a copy/paste error to be more likely as this isn't a fully MCVE in the first place.

Comment: You can change the accept mark if you want @A.Raza. You can't accept multiple answers. Personally, I tend to not accept answers on meta at all unless they actually fixed something (e.g. in case of bug reports). Meta is discussion, and typically doesn't have one true "correct" answer. Either way, the choice is yours.

Comment: Definitely never edit the code in someone else's question as often they copy-paste it and an error with the code is likely the reason for their question.

Comment: I would not have added the missing `}` (in fact, I was told not to do that in an edit) as in many cases the missing characters *is* the source of the issue (or one of the many) - which leads to the question in the first place.  Fixing the source would mean the question is answered in the edit...

Comment: In general principle I agree @Clonkex, but in the specific case of a missing closing character in an obviously incomplete code snippet I've found that they are virtually always copy/paste errors, especially when the entire question is badly formatted (as in this case). In almost all other cases you're completely correct, don't edit typos in the question's code! Feel free to further edit the question if you think it can be improved!

Comment: I agree with @Clonkex. Especially as a PHP "white screen of death" can be caused by the syntax errors such as a missing ending-bracket (also it could be valid and their are no results or a database issue or....). For beginners it can be hard to understand that the error on line 45, which is just a `}`, is actually cause at line 7 where they missed an ending bracket (if they even have error reporting on or understand where to find the logs). I would have left it alone in this case but maybe I just teach beginners too much and have a biased point of view :).

Comment: Adding in the 'missing' `}` would be pointless; clearly the snippet is missing more code, as it would only contain two variable assignments which are then not used for anything. Snippets will always be snippets - incomplete. Trying to salvage them in any way is conflicting with the author's intent.

Answer (score 16):

I'd have probably rejected and improved the edit due to it not modifying, really, the only thing that needed to be modified.

The sentence, "I used it to retrieve the current products in cart but it return blank page", is grammatically incorrect; I would have replaced it with, "I used this to retrieve the current products in the card, but it returns a blank page."  Further, adding bold to that section takes away more than it helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand, Now I got it.

Comment: should I delete this question now or leave it?

Comment: Since it has an upvote, you can't; I recommend leaving it anyway since it's good to have this kind of information around anyway.

Comment: in this case would it have been better to reject and edit or an improve edit (for carrying over the edit and fixing it) than just a plain reject?

Comment: @Memor-X:  You could do a plain reject if you didn't feel like editing it yourself in that scenario, but I feel like the edit's so minor, if one's already reviewing it, there's not much effort needed to do that little extra effort. But who am I to dictate one's schedule?

Comment: Would you have really left in the quote formatting? I agree that the grammar needed to be corrected, I'm just surprised you see that as the only problem with the original post.

Comment: @BSMP: I will admit to having some temporary vision problems right now.  In all frankness, "yellow" is a bit much for me right now, and I hadn't really noticed the blockquote in the tiny picture.  That'd also be something I would remove.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.

Comment: Well, that would have been a bad edit, since the original says "cart" and your potential replacement says "card" :P.

Comment: Vision problems notwithstanding, I just can't upvote an answer that says *"...it not modifying, really, the only thing that needed to be modified"*. It isn't just a readability issue to misuse quote formatting, it is a *semantic* one.